# Fix the following errors

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have the following VB.Net code Im trying  to fix:

```
Public Delegate Sub RequestHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ManageEventArgs)  



Public Custom Event RequestEvent As RequestHandler
            AddHandler(value As RequestHandler)

            End AddHandler
            RemoveHandler(value As RequestHandler)

            End RemoveHandler
            RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As ManageEventArgs)

            End RaiseEvent
        End Event  



Public Function Request(ByVal bizID As String, ByVal Optional table As Hashtable = Nothing) As ArrayList
            Me.aList = New ArrayList
            If (Not Me.RequestEvent Is Nothing) Then
                Dim e As New ManageEventArgs(bizID, table)
                Me.RequestEvent.Invoke(Me, e)
            End If
            Return Me.aList
        End Function
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   BC32022 'Public Event RequestEvent As Manage.RequestHandler' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

VB.Net isn't my preferred language so any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Plutonix, you should check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/event-statement) out to see that that syntax is valid, although pointless here if no code is to be added to those blocks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks!  I didnt know it could be used as a block.  In part because `End AddHandler` just doesnt sound right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way:

```
Public Event RequestEvent(sender As Object, e As ManageEventArgs)
```

and then:

```
Public Function Request(bizID As String, Optional table As Hashtable = Nothing) As ArrayList
  Dim aList As New ArrayList

  RaiseEvent RequestEvent(Me, New ManageEventArgs(bizID, table))

  Return aList
End Function
```

I'm not sure what's going on with your aList thingy.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. honestly I dont know either concerning the aList. All I got was a heap of decompiled VB.Net code dumped in my work folder..